# How do I render React components dynamically using props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and don't quite understand how to dynamically render components based on props.

For practice, I'm building a credit card validator which works well.  Once the information is valid, I want to render my component to display a thank you message. I've added a property "mode" that contains "default". My thinking is that this prop would then change to "thankYouScreen" when the credit card info is validated. When this prop changes to "thankYouScreen" it would render the ThankYouMessage component.

Is this how one would go about this?

**Components**

```
import React from 'react';
import PaymentStore from './../store/paymentStore';

class InitialPaymentScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="pay-form">
        <div className="pay-form-wrapper">
          <div className="pay-form-title">Payment Information</div>
          <form className="payment-form js-error-hook" onSubmit={this.props.store.init.bind(this.props.store)}>
            <div className="payment-form-wrap payment-form-cc-name">
              <label className="payment-form-label">Name on Card</label>
              <input className="payment-form-input js-cc-name" maxLength="50" placeholder="Enter your name..." type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div className="payment-form-wrap payment-form-cc">
              <label className="payment-form-label">Card Number</label>
              <input className="payment-form-input js-cc-number" placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456" type="number"/>
            </div>
            <div className="payment-form-wrap payment-form-exp">
              <label className="payment-form-label">Expiration</label>
              <input className="payment-form-input js-cc-expiration" placeholder="04/17" type="number" min="0"/>
            </div>
            <div className="payment-form-wrap payment-form-cvv">
              <label className="payment-form-label">CVV</label>
              <input className="payment-form-input js-cc-cvv" placeholder="123" type="number"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" className="payment-form-submit" onClick={this.props.store.init.bind(this.props.store)} value="Next" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ThankYouMessage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>Thanks!</div>
    );

  }
}

class PaymentForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="main-content payment-form-wrapper">
        <InitialPaymentScreen store={this.props.route.store} mode="default"/>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

**Store**

```
let PaymentStore = {
  validateFields() {
    // Validates all the information
  },
  displayThankYou(){
    console.log("Thanks!") 
    // I'm assuming this is where I should update "mode" to render the component
  },
};
```

Comment: In the way you have started, your view is not aware of your store updates. There are solution like react-redux that implements a action/store model (like in Flux). But if you don't master these concepts yet, and if you are new to React, I would suggest instead to try to make your state to live with the component. Using React state: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html

Comment: Ah, so if I wanted to continue with what I have, I would need to use an event-emitter which would fire off an event to let my view know of the validation change in my store?

Comment: yeah, if you want to follow that path that can work with an event emitter. You can trigger a re-render from withing a component with `this.forceUpdate()`